# ubuntu 16.04 set metadada failed gedit

Tags: gtk, metadata, gedit, ubuntu-16.04

Is any one could help me to stop this behavior of gedit in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have upgraded 14.04 to 16.04 . Now i am trying to open the gedit from terminal by passing the command sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list but it is throwing an error stating that (gedit:2090): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

however, it is opening the file. when i am trying to save any modification then it is showing error after saving the file as (gedit:2090): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

I am not getting why this is happening in 16.04 only it was not with the 14.04.

I tried to look for a solution but could not find any. Please if any one has any idea or solution regarding these issues please share your expertise.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use kate (a nice GUI editor) instead of gedit.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kate
gksudo kate /path/file.txt
```

You can customize kate, and I think you will like it better than gedit.

Comment: You do not have an answer to his problem. You are merely suggesting a different software.

Answer (score -4):

You can use command: `sudo nano gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Umm... won't that just to try edit a file called gedit in your cwd?